# ArcGIS geoprocessing/extraction tool for online use

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I'm looking to extract data from raster cells using drawn polygons in an online app through ArcGIS Online.

I would like to use the draw widget on AGOL to create a polygon layer, and use that layer to extract/summarize data from a raster, and perform a calculation using that data. Is that possible?

Ideally, it would create the area under the drawn area, and also provide statistics based on raster data (sum total, sd + mean) that are within the drawn area. If possible i would also like a calculated field for the resulting data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is possible, using ArcGIS WebApps.

You can use the Draw widget, and customize the widget to create a selectable layer. Then using the Analyst widget, you can use the polygons generated in the draw widget to calculate basic statistics on the area of interest in the raster.

Still working on a solution to making your own calculated field or a custom calculation within the Analysis widget.